# Plotting Timeseries with map() from purrr

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts, forecasting, purrr

I am trying to generate a plot that is similar to this:

[image]

A walkthrough is provided here -> https://medium.com/@erickramer/beautiful-data-science-with-functional-programming-and-r-a3f72059500b

However the code supplied on this website isn't generating a plot for me, instead I get this error:

```
> forecasts1 = tsdf %>%
+     map(auto.arima) %>%
+     map(forecast, h=10)
Error in is.constant(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

This is despite the fact that I have replicated their data formatting precisely. Here are our datasets for comparison:

```
> str(tsdf)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   89 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ time_series:List of 89
  ..$ 1_1  : Time-Series  from 2013 to 2017: 8981338 10707490 11410597 10816217 12263765 ...
  ..$ 1_10 : Time-Series  from 2013 to 2017: 12645212 13510638 13133558 13542970 16074675 ...
  ..$ 1_2  : Time-Series  from 2013 to 2017: 19028892 20626896 19952328 20865263 22547313 ...
  ..$ 1_3  : Time-Series  from 2013 to 2017: 7081624 8317481 8374427 8330653 9643845 ...
  ..$ 1_4  : Time-Series  from 2013 to 2017: 25421637 30934941 30756101 27977317 32417608 ...
```

And the provided example data (upon which the code did work, according to the website):

```
> str(time_series)
List of 9
 $ Germany    : Time-Series [1:52] from 1960 to 2011: 684721 716424 749838   ...
 $ Singapore  : Time-Series [1:52] from 1960 to 2011: 7208 7795 8349   ...
 $ Finland    : Time-Series [1:37] from 1975 to 2011: 85842 86137 86344   ...
```

I can't seem to figure it out, though it may have something to do with the fact that their timeseries has one solid endpoint, yet my timeseries have several different monthly endpoints.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

*** UPDATE ***

After applying Akruns suggestion I stored exclusively the time-series vector in a list like so:

```
tsdf <- akrun %>%
select(time_series)
```

I then fit the model like this:

```
tsdf$time_series %>% map(auto.arima) %>%
map(forecast, h=12)
```

...and then the plot...

... looks awful.

[image]

Do I need to convert y_axis scale? Or do some sort of differencing to the data before plotting the arima? Really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: You may need `tsdf$time_series%>% map(auto.arima) %>%` .  if you notice the structure from the website.  It is a `list` of time series, where as yours is a `data.frame` with 1 column that is a `list` of time series.  So, extract that column with `$` or `[[` and then apply the functions

Comment: Thank you Akrun! Posting update now

Comment: BTW, I was able to replicate the plots from the website as well

Comment: @Akrun Updated :)

Comment: Could you `dput` a sample of data for folks here to work with?